# Differences from dpm and dsm for devel module for debugging objects?

Tags: debugging

What are the differences of dpm and dsm for the devel module? I mainly use dsm for the devel module. What are some other common debugging functions that are useful in the devel module?

Comment: I answered "differences" part. "Some other common debugging functions" would render this question too broad in my eyes, consider removing it. Especially when it is already covered by [demo page](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) linked fom project page.

Comment: Even that doc is a little wrong, as `dpm()` will normally use krumo and not `print_r`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7):

> Legacy function that was poorly named.
>
> Use dpm() instead, since the 'p' maps to 'print_r'.
>
> Code
>
> ```
> function dsm($input, $name = NULL) {
>   return dpm($input, $name);
> }
> ```

So there is no real difference, except the function you are using is left there for developers that failed to switch when it was renamed.

Answer (score 2):

dpm() prints a variable to the ‘message’ area of the page using drupal_set_message(). The output and compact and less likely to break the layout of your page.

From the devel docs:

> A note from the devel module: dsm() is a legacy function that was
>   poorly named; use dpm() instead, since the 'p' maps to 'print_r'.

I think we should trust the devel folks on that one.